# Adding header to Quicktabs result

Tags: views, blocks, entities

I am using [Quicktabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) to format the results of a view and it works fine. I created my layout so that my results will look like a table (with 3 columns).

I need to add a header at the top of the rows but before the tabs.

Any ideas how can I do this?

I am relatively new to Drupal.

Comment: May be you need to use its respective tpl files and make changes in it.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will not involve modifying templates. I looked into creating a view within a view but for some reason I get no results: maybe I'm not linking the views properly?

Comment: Can you please provide rough idea about what you want? I can't understand the question

Comment: Tbh I can't remember what I did but I probably used the tpl files for that. The question was posted in 2012 though (like, 2 years ago) :)